# error: src refspec master does not match any

Tags: git, github, git-push

Выдает ошибку, не знаю как правильно с ней справится

```
git push org master

error: src refspec master does not match any 
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/devmafia/PythonCodes.git
```

Comment: Попробуйте git push -u origin master

Comment: а на что влияет такой формат вызова?
ошибку выдало ту же

Comment: Параметр -u устанавливает upstream

Comment: Если это пустой репозиторий, то сначала Вам неободимо что-то закоммитить. То есть выполнить следующие действия: 1) git add . 2) git commit -m "Initial commit" 3) git push -u origin master

Comment: 2 сопутствующих вопроса:
1) У меня есть один большой репозитарий, если я пытаюсь его запушить, то выходит такая вот ошибка:
fatal: adding files failed, с чем может быть связана эта ошибка?
2) что такое upstream ?

Comment: *Upstream* с английского переводится как *восходящий поток*, *downstream* соответственно *нисходящий*. Или восходящий — от вас вверх, нисходящий  — от вас вниз. В терминах GitHub и вашего компьютера (репозиторий изначально ваш) GitHub == upstream, ваш компьютер == downstream. Стало понятнее?

Comment: А вообще, конечно, надо добавить в вопрос вывод команды `git remote -v`. И читать https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line.

Comment: вывод git remote -v:
 git remote -v
org     https://github.com/devmafia/PythonCodes.git (fetch)
org     https://github.com/devmafia/PythonCodes.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:devmafia/PythonCodes.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:devmafia/PythonCodes.git (push)

Comment: Да, стало, только еще одно уточнение.
У меня получилось запушить папку входящую в репозиторий, который я изначально хотел запушить, так ошибки не выдает (и без -u), cоответсвенно вопрос: "а когда обязательно писать -u, а когда можно и без него и можно писать -d?"
и в чем может быть причина ошибки:
fatal: adding files failed 

От того, что здесь написано в принципе не откланялся:
https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line

Comment: 0andriy, так могли ли вы бы мне пожалуйста дать ответ на мой вопрос?